# R if statement in a function with a fomula argument

Tags: r, function, if-statement

```
testing<-function(formula=NULL,data=NULL){
  if(with(data,formula)==T){
print('YESSSS')
  }
}
A<-matrix(1:16,4,4)
colnames(A)<-c('x','y','z','gg')
A<-as.data.frame(A)
testing(data=A,formula=(2*x+y==Z))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found 
##or I can put formula=(x=1)
##reason that I use formula is because my dataset had different location and I would want
##to 'subset' my data into different set
```

This is the main flow of my code. I had done some search and seems to be no one ask this kind of stupid question or it is not possible to pass a formula in a if statement. Thank you in advance

Comment: You have a `matrix` and you are calling `with`

Comment: it is a dataframe, sorry for casuing trouble

Comment: @vincentchau you need to tweak your logic. Inside the `if` statement, you will be generating a vector of boolean and the first value will only be evaluated.

Comment: I am assuming you want to `subset ` A.

Comment: even if I use subset,it cannot fulfill the condition of 2*x+y==Z or maybe even x^2+y^2=z^2

Comment: also, you are using capital `Z` while the your column name is `z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want `subset` of your data.frame create a `character` object representing the formula like this:

```
formula="2*x+y==z"
testing<-function(data,formula){with(data = data,expr = eval(parse(text = formula)))}
subset(A,testing(A,formula=formula))

#x y  z gg
#2 2 6 10 14
```

You can change the formula as per your need.

Comment: This look like a promising method to solve the problem. This method is clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to evaluate it, one option is `eval(parse`

```
testing<-function(formula=NULL,data=NULL){
 data <- deparse(substitute(data))
 if(any(eval(parse(text=paste("with(", data, ",", 
              deparse(substitute(formula)), ")")))))
  print("YESSS")
 }

testing(data=A,formula=(2*x+y==z))
#[1] "YESSS"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in R it evaluates its arguments first before executing the function.

For example, `prod(2+2, 3)` is first turned into `prod(4, 3)` before the function `prod()` is even called.

Thus, in your code, R starts by trying to solve `(2*x+y==Z)`. It fails because there is no x object outside of the function code. So, it not even begin running `testing()`.

To use your function correctly you should make it clear to R that it is not supposed to calculate `(2*x+y==Z)`. Instead  it should pass this information as is. You could do that using the functions `expression()` and `eval()`.

```
testing<-function(formula=NULL,data=NULL){
   if(with(data,eval(formula==T)){
print('YESSSS')
  }
}
A<-matrix(1:16,4,4)
colnames(A)<-c('x','y','z','gg')
A<-as.data.frame(A)
testing(data=A,formula=expression(2*x+y==Z))
```

However, you will notice that there other problems with your code.

- For Z is different than z. Notice that the in colnames you use z and in the formula Z.
- The if() only works for when there is a single value of true or false. In your case, you will have one value for each row in A. When this happens, if() will only check if the first row fits the criteria.

If your purpose is subsetting, it is much more easier to do:

```
  A.subset <- subset(A, 2*A$x+A$y == A$z)
```

Comment: A.subset <- subset(A, 2*A$x+A$y == A$z)
this is a way to solve the problem, but what if i use a different equation to perform the subset?

Comment: Any equation should work, for example: subset(A, 2*A$x^A$y == A$z), subset(A, 3*A$x == A$z), subset(A, 2*A$x^A$y+A$z==1).

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion with my colleague, 
here is a kind of solution

```
testing<-function(cx,cy,px,py,z,data=NULL){
  list<-NULL
  for(m in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(cx*data$x[m]^px+cy*data$y[m]^py+data$z==0){
    print(m)}
  }
}
```

but this can deal with polynomial only and with a lot of arguments in the function. I am think of a way to reduce it as a general equation.or maybe this is the most easiest equation.